# Correct way of preventing duplicated values from being stored in spring hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am currently working on a program that is using Spring and Hibernate to retrieve data every 31 seconds (Spring scheduled service) and save to mysql tables (Hibernate).

I currently have a HashMap that is checking the data retrieved.  If the data retrieved is in the HashMap, use that instance.  If the data is not in the HashMap, add it to the HashMap and save this new entry through Hibernate.

My only concern with this design is that since this is a Spring schedule service that runs every 31 seconds, would the HashMap object also get recreated every 31 seconds?  In that case, any entries previously added to the HashMap will not be on there anymore, and duplicated entries will be saved to the table right?

What would be the best practice to solve this issue?  Thanks.

My code:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 31000)
public void saveCompanyData() {               

            // Retrieve data from online into Data
            ...
            ...

            // Hibernate
            SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
            .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
            .addAnnotatedClass(Company.class)
            .buildSessionFactory();
            Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
            session.beginTransaction();

            // Create HashMap
            HashMap<String, Company> companyMap = new HashMap<>();

            // Save to table if key not mapped
            String companyKey = Data.getCompanyName();
            Company company;
            if(companyMap.containsKey(companyKey)){
                company = companyMap.get(companyKey);
            } else {
                company = new company(Data.getCompanyName());
                companyMap.put(companyKey, company);
                session.save(company);
            }

            // Commit
            session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
HashMap<String, Company> companyMap = new HashMap<>()
```

The Above line of code would definitely create a new object and add it to Database as per the further written code.

In your current implementation you would have to create a global HashMap reference that is initialized once either by using singleton bean or by using a static variable.

But the same would not work once your application is restarted.

You should go for checking into the database if the row exists or not using `session.get` method and further insert into Database if row doesnot exist.

Or you could just use `session.saveOrUpdate` as it would just update the row.

For the above 2 methods to work you would have to define the companyName as identifier in the hibernate mapping file ( `hibernate.cfg.xml` in your case)